# Fast networking (JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray)

Tags: java, android, json

I am very worried about this issue. It always throws an exception:

> `JSONObject` cannot converted to `JSONArray`

This is in Android. Here is the code:

```
  AndroidNetworking.post(url)
                        .addBodyParameter("moving_item", moving.getText().toString())
                        .addBodyParameter("vehical_move", v)
                        .addBodyParameter("pick_up", starting.getText().toString())
                        .addBodyParameter("lat_pickup", String.valueOf(strlat))
                        .addBodyParameter("lng_pickup", String.valueOf(strlng))
                        .addBodyParameter("lat_dropoff", String.valueOf(endlat))
                        .addBodyParameter("lng_dropoff", String.valueOf(endlng))
                        .addBodyParameter("description",descriptionbox.getText().toString())
                        .addBodyParameter("date",dateserv)
                         .addBodyParameter("email", emailtextfield.getText().toString())
                        .addBodyParameter("price", pricebox.getText().toString())
                        .addBodyParameter("comments", detailedbox.getText().toString())
                        .addBodyParameter("loadtype", drop)
                        .addBodyParameter("drop_off", destination.getText().toString())
                        .addBodyParameter("distance",dsitnc)
                        .addBodyParameter("image1" , String.valueOf(imageFile1))
                        .addBodyParameter("image2" ,String.valueOf(imageFile2))
                        .addBodyParameter("image3" , String.valueOf(imageFile3))
                        .setPriority(Priority.HIGH)
                        .build()
                        .getAsString(new StringRequestListener() {
                            public void onResponse(String response)
                            {
                                try {
                                 /*   JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(new String(response));
                                    JSONArray mtUsers = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("result");
                                    JSONObject jsonObject = mtUsers.getJSONObject(0);
                                    String resu = jsonObject.optString("result");
        */
                                /*    JSONArray res = new JSONObject(response).getJSONArray("result");
                                    JSONArray mes = new JSONObject(response).getJSONArray("message");*/
                                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                                   // JSONObject jsonObject1 = mes.getJSONObject(0);
                                    //JSONArray result1 = new JSONObject(response).getJSONArray("result");
                                    String result = jsonObject.getString("result");
                                    String message = jsonObject.getString("message");
```

Comment: post the errors log and the whole json response

Comment: it cannot give error in logcat when i hit this funtion it going thrugh an exception and shows the message that jason object cannot converted to jason array

Comment: post the json response

Comment: post your json response here.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);

JSONArray jsonArray = object.getJSONArray("");

JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
String result = jsonObject.getString("result");
String message = jsonObject.getString("message");
```

instead

at line `object.getJSONArray("")` put into string root array name (if it doesn't have name, try leave it empty)

Answer (score 0):

Response that you get is not an `JSONArray` , so log it first . Use [JSONViewer](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/)

```
 private void parseResponse(String response) throws JSONException {

    Log.d(TAG, "parseResponse:RESPONSE "+response);

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.optJSONArray("array_key");

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

        JSONObject arrayObject = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);

    }

}
```

Comment: what you get  in log ,Log.d(TAG, "parseResponse:RESPONSE "+response);

Comment: it shows the same error org.json.jsonexception : value<div of type java.lang.string cannot be converted to jsonarray

Comment: .getAsString(new StringRequestListener() {
                            public void onResponse(String response)
                            {                                                            parseResponse(response) ;                                                                        
            }}

Comment: it shows the same error org.json.jsonexception : value<div of type java.lang.string cannot be converted to jsonarray

Comment: .build()
                        .getAsString(new StringRequestListener() {
                            public void onResponse(String response)
                            {                                                                                                                                    
                          Log.d(TAG, "parseResponse:RESPONSE "+response);  //Comment all code just do log what u get
                              }    }